# Windows 7 - C set as Active Partition, Boot Issue, System Not Yet Restarted

Tags: partitioning, disk-management

I recently accidentally set C as "Active" in Disk Management. I realized my possible mistake when it was too late. The other partition on the same physical drive is 100MB and shows as the "Recovery Partition" (please see image).

[Disk Management Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEwOD.jpg)

Since I have not yet restarted my computer, should I run a "System Restore" to fix the possible issue?

Answer (score 1):

Active means you are booting from it. In your case, the 100MB junk partition is actually where the OS boot files are. Change the 100MB one back to active and the fact that you marked C as active should not influence anything.

It's just a marker, not a boot editing alteration.

To clarify definitions:

The system partition (or system volume) is a primary partition that contains the boot loader (Boot Configuration Database, Boot Manager Code, Windows Recovery Environment and reserves space for the startup files which may be required by BitLocker), meaning you can select to boot from there.

The boot partition (or boot volume) is the disk partition that contains the operating system folder, known as the system root.

Active, means you have selected to boot from the specific partition.
You can have only an active one.

Comment: Would running "System Restore" negate any changes made and restore partition settings as they were?

Comment: Don't do that, just make the 100MB one active again and the system will normally boot from there.

Comment: The system will only allow for 1 active partition per physical drive. So if I did run "System Restore", would that negate the partition changes, or are partition changes outside the scope of restoration?

Comment: No, that's something outside the scope. If you don't change the setting back and restart, you'll have to use boot fix tools to change it back (practically do the same thing from a diskpart loaded from Windows original disk).

Comment: The 100MB partition does not say "System" but rather says "Recovery Partition". Does this possibly mean that this partition is not the "System" partition?

Comment: I added some details about system partition. What's important for you is to have the active partition marked correctly.

Comment: Ok, but how do I know which partition is the "System" partition? None of the partitions say "System". Although the C does say "Boot" (please see image).

Answer (score 0):

I discovered...

Only 1 partition on a physical disk can be set as "Active". The "System" partition must be set as "Active". To determine which partition is the "System" partition go to command prompt and run `diskpart` then:

```
list disk
select disk 0
list partition
select partition 1
detail partition
```

This will show details of that partition. Once you have determined which disk is the "System" disk, set it as "Active" by:

```
list disk
select disk 0
list partition
select partition 1
active
```

Finally, restart the computer to verify setting completion.

Comment: This shows you exactly what the GUI in disk management shows you.